# Angular: Unable to bind to events such as click and change on a dynamically loaded component

Tags: angular, event-binding, angular-dynamic-components

I have created 2 angular 5 components that are a dialog box and a drop-down.

I wanted to open the drop-down component in the dialog box so I created a dialog service for it that is injected in the app.component. The code in app.component is as follows-

```
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
constructor(private dialog: DialogService){}
openDialog(){
    this.dialog.open(TestComponent, {
      modal: true
    });
  }
```

TestComponent is very simple, it has the component selector in HTML file which looks like this-

```
<once-ui-dropdown
  [options]="customLanguages"
  [allowSearch]="true">
</once-ui-dropdown>
```

Where customLanguages is an array of options.

DialogService is a simple service which does two things-

**1) Adding a dialog component to body**

Here is the code snippet-

```
DialogService.componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
      .resolveComponentFactory(DialogComponent)
      .create(this.injector);

this.appRef.attachView(DialogService.componentRef.hostView);

const domElem = (DialogService.componentRef.hostView as 
                EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
                .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

document.body.appendChild(domElem);

DialogService.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

**2: Opens/Appends the TestComponent to a div in Dialog box**

```
    const loadComponentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(content)
            .create(this.injector);

   loadComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

   const domElem = (loadComponentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
            .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

   data = domElem.innerHTML;

   document.getElementById('loadComponent').innerHTML = data;
```

Last thing `<once-ui-dropdown` is an angular 5 component which has some function like openDialog, changeOptions etc. and its HTML looks like this-

```
<div class="dropholder" (click)="this.openDropdown()" 
...
...
...
```

**Now, the problem is that "I am able to bind the data/props (the options array) to dropdown component but the events such click and change are not being called. Seems some problem with the event binding on the dynamically loaded component.". Please help!**

Comment: Hey would you create a [mcve] in StackBlitz or like editor please?